# How to show JSON object in a HTML table?

Tags: javascript, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have created springboot application and i have two HTML pages as "icecream.html" and "orders.html". Now i want to retrieve data from my order table (in postgresql) and show them as a orders.html page.

This is my controller class for orders

```
@RestController(value = "/icecream") 
public class OrderController {
    @Autowired 
    public IcecreamDao icecreamDao; 

    @GetMapping("/orders") 
    public List<Icecream> icecreamInformation() {
        List<Icecream> icecreams = icecreamDao.getData(); 
        return icecreams; 
    }

}
```

This is my orders.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="js/call.js"> </script>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></ script >

    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"> </ script >
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"> </ script >

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            productList();
            });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="starter-template">
            <fieldset>
                <h1> <u>Your Order</u> </h1>

                <table id = "productTable" border="1">
                    <th>Order Number</th>
                    <th>Order Date</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Item Name</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my call .js file

```
function productList() {
    $.ajax({
        url :'/orders',
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(icecreamList) {
            productListSuccess(icecreamList);
        },
        error : function(request, message, error) {
            handleException(request, message, error);
        }
    });
}

function productListSuccess(icecreamList) {

    $.each(icecreamList, function(index, product) {
        productAddRow(product);
    });
}

function productAddRow(product) {

    if ($("#productTable tbody").length == 0) {
        $("#productTable").append("<tbody></tbody>");
    }
    $("#productTable tbody").append(productBuildTableRow(product));
}

function productBuildTableRow(product) {

    var ret = "<tr>" + "<td>" + product.name + "</td>" + "<td>" +product.price
            + "</td>" + "<td>" + product.qty + "</td>" + "<td>" + product.total
            + "</td>" + "</tr>";
    return ret;
}

function handleException(request, message, error) {

    var msg = "";
    msg += "Code: " + request.status + "\n";
    msg += "Text: " + request.statusText + "\n";
    if (request.responseJSON != null) {
        msg += "Message" + request.responseJSON.Message + "\n";
    }
    alert(msg);
 }
```

It is successfully giving a set of data from my DB. But not giving it as my html page. Please someone guide me about what went wrong...

Comment: did my answer below resolve your issue? please update your question with more details or mark the answer if it was helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have copied in your HTML & JS to this snippet. Since you say that the ajax is coming back successfully i have only included the happy js path with some test data.
the only issue i see with it is that you dont have order number or order date in your data obj. as a result your table will be off to the header. 
Since these functions included below are working i would recommend using your developer tools to see if there is a syntax error that is blowing up your js. My guess is if you move your script tag from the front of the html to the back everything would start clicking. to confirm that use your developer console. its probably going to throw an error about how your HTML element doesnt exist since the js is executing before your html is finished loading. a safe rule of thumb is always stick js at the bottom of the file.

```js
function productListSuccess(icecreamList) {

    $.each(icecreamList, function(index, product) {
        productAddRow(product);
    });
}

function productAddRow(product) {

    if ($("#productTable tbody").length == 0) {
        $("#productTable").append("<tbody></tbody>");
    }
    $("#productTable tbody").append(productBuildTableRow(product));
}

function productBuildTableRow(product) {

    var ret = "<tr>" + "<td>" + product.name + "</td>" + "<td>" +product.price
            + "</td>" + "<td>" + product.qty + "</td>" + "<td>" + product.total
            + "</td>" + "</tr>";
    return ret;
}
productListSuccess([
  {
    name: 'Test 1',
    price: 1,
    qty: 1,
    total: 1
   },
   {
    name: 'Test 2',
    price: 2,
    qty: 2,
    total: 4
   }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="starter-template">
            <fieldset>
                <h1> <u>Your Order</u> </h1>

                <table id = "productTable" border="1">
                    <th>Order Number</th>
                    <th>Order Date</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Item Name</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```